# Allah's guidance for non-Muslims up to the age of 40

Tags: practical-islam, allah, non-muslim, conversion

I heard from the older folks in my community that, Allah's guidance for non-Muslims will be till the age of 40. Which means, Allah will show them all the signs for them to convert until they reach the age of 40, anything beyond that, Allah doesn't help.

But then again, this theory doesn't make sense, as there are people who convert way beyond 40.

Can I get any Hadith supporting or not supporting the theory?

Comment: Not familiar with that particular interpretation, but it's likely based on [Al 'Ahqaf 15-16](http://quran.com/46/15-16).  Perhaps digging up tafasir which cover those ayat would help.

Comment: There is a story of yore I once came across of Prophet Abraham (AS) and an old man who worshipped the sun, and Abraham (AS) got angry with him (and so on), and eventually the old man reverted to Islam... however unsure if it is a reliable hadith or not. The point is, Allah's Guidance may come to anyone at any age.

Comment: Had it been the case, then no non-muslim have become a muslim after 40 years. But that is not the case. People from all ages are converting to Islam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This theory isn't true.
Allah will guide all human in every age, even all creatures if he wills. According to:

> He said, "Our Lord is He who gave each thing its form and then guided
>   [it]."Surat Ţāhā,verse50
>
> "Who created and proportioned,And Who destined and [then] guided"Surat
>   Al-'A`lá,verse 2-3
>
> "... And Allah guides whom He wills to a straight path."Surat
>   Al-Baqarah,verse213
>
> "Verily, Allah sends astray whom He wills, and guides whom He
>   wills."surat Faatir,verse8
>
> "Then Allah misleads whom He wills and guides whom He wills."surat
>   Ibrahim,verse4
>
> "But He sends astray whom He wills and guides whom He wills."surat
>   An-Nahl,verse93

Etc...

On the other hand There are many verses in the Qur`an which confirm the free will of the human being, such as:

> "Indeed We have guided him to the way, be he grateful or
>   ungrateful."Surat Al-'Insān,verse3
>
> "And say, "The truth is from your Lord, so whoever wills - let him
>   believe; and whoever wills - let him disbelieve...."Surat
>   Al-Kahf,verse29
>
> "A group [of you] He guided, and a group deserved [to be in] error.
>   Indeed, they had taken the devils as allies instead of Allah while
>   they thought that they were guided."Surat Al-'A`rāf,verse30

Etc...

So, This ability to choose is a measure of guidance from Allah (awj).human being is a free being and can choose to take the path of Divine guidance—thereby preparing in himself the grounds for further guidance—or he could choose to take the opposite direction, which leads to disbelief and oppression. So, if the human being decided to walk on to the path of disbelief and oppression, he would be naturally deprived of Divine guidance. But if he chose to traverse the path of truth, he would be blessed by that Divine guidance, without any limitation on age.